# I am trying to use the useMemo hook for this form for the name

Tags: reactjs

So this is the code for the form.  I was wondering how to useMemo for the components name, long, short, entry... thanks!

```
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(''); //the components to put useMemo on

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log({name, long, short, entry, exit})
    };
  
  return (
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> //form that enters in the data
      <label>
        Symbol:
        <br />
        <input name="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/> //sets the name value
      </label>
      <br />
      <input type = "submit" value="whatisname"/>
     </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use `useMemo()`? The hook is used to [return a memoized value](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) and your fields are just values. They do not need to be re-computed on change, they just hold data.

To elaborate a little more on that, let's say you have a text field and you want to remove all characters from it that are contained in an array `bannedChars = ['a', 'b', 'c'];`. This is a somewhat appropriate use for `useMemo()` since it is a heavy operation and we can take advantage of `useMemo()`'s memoization.

```js
const bannedChars = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function removeBannedChars(str) {
  bannedChars.forEach(c => str = str.replace(c, ''));
  return str;
}

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const sanitized = useMemo(() => {
    return removeBannedChars(value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <input
      name="value"
      value={sanitized}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}
```

This will run on every change of `value` (on every keypress) and remove the banned characters from it. It will return the "sanitized" value, which will be saved to `sanitized`.

Comment: <input name="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/> for this line I was wondering how I could enter in useMemo for it so that if you enter the same name it doesn't change.

Comment: That is not really what `useMemo()` is for.